# Рекомендуемые товары на основе просмотренных товаров пользователем (PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, использую для создания интернет магазина PHP и СУБД MySQL. Загорелся желанием сделать рекомендуемые товары на основе просмотров. Табличка с просмотрами уже есть (id, product_id, user_id, date). Пока что не могу сообразить как реализовать данную задачу. Интересно ваше решение. Прошу примерный алгоритм как это выполнить, либо ресурс где это уже делали (из поиска только нашел примеры с CMS). Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Ищете пользователей, которые смотрели такие же товары (выбираете некий % совпадения) и берете товары, которые они так же смотрели, но еще не смотрел тот для кого подбираем. Выбираем из них такие товары, которые попадаются не менее чем у N посмотревших. Реализуется одним запросом в БД

Comment: Спасибо за совет, это интересное решение данной задачи, но я хотел не совсем это.Я не просто так написал "на основе просмотров товаров пользователем, то есть одним человеком ". Хочу отталкиваться от того,что именно пользователь смотрел и уже это использовать. Если делать так,как Вы сказали,то может получиться,что я порекомендую товары например из категории ноутбуки, хотя пользователь просматривал допустим планшеты. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает, информация из воздуха не возьмется. Если не анализировать статистику, то вам надо самому завести в БД к какому товару что надо показывать. И что то мне подсказывает, что вам понадобится сотрудник который постоянно будет это анализировать и добавлять в БД